# Why do I get instruments - "Target failed to run"?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, instruments

> Target failed to run: Remote exception encountered: Faild to get task for pid 3103

[image: Target failed to run]

I'm running iPhone OS 3.1.3 on the device and I can run my App in debug mode on the device.

I downloaded and installed the xcode_3.2.2_and_iphone_sdk_3.2_final.dmg twice, without any luck.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I have two applications installed on my device with the **same name** resp. the **same Bundle display name**: Doublemill. Since they have different bundle identifiers, the debugger can deal with that, however Instruments seems to be confused.

Comment: Seems like you should file a bug so Apple can fix this!

Comment: Thanks, I had to remove all versions of the app and restart XCode ("it just works" my ass), but it helped!

Comment: **WORKED** Had two version of an app like you. +1 for question and answer both.

Answer (score 54):

I got the same issue when I switched to XCode 4 and I solved it by setting my release code-signing profile to my development profile instead of the app store profile that was previously set. Indeed, Xcode 4 profiles your app using the release build by default.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, but I had the exact same problem and instead changed the "Profile" scheme to use Debug instead of Release - that solved it (although I would prefer the Release build).  Not sure why it made a difference; your explanation seems valid/reasonable but didn't work for me.

Comment: I double checked my provisioning to be development and remove Entitlements. That fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. In Xcode 4.3.2 -- under schemes dropdown in the upper right, edit scheme, choose the profile option on the left of the resulting popup, change the build configuration to "Debug".

Comment: Makdads comment worked for me, Click Product-> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Profile XYZ.app and change the build configuration to debug or appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Hey.
There can also be some other issues.

Provisioning Profile.
From Apple documentation:
*For your protection, the instrument does not allow you to process any application that is not
code-signed with your provisioning profile. This includes any copy that has been downloaded from the iTunes App Store.*

Device.
Instrumetns UIAutomation doesn't work on iPhone 3G, only 3Gs, 4.

Sadly support for instruments is bad. Apple doesn't seem to put much attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI for those running from the command line and getting the same issue, you have to use the fully qualified path to the application or instruments will blow up (with a relative path).  That was a good waste of a couple hours tracking that down.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you having this issues set your "Code Signing Identity" to IOS Developer, see below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I using distribute provisioning profile in Release, change to development provisioning profile will fix that.