# Instruments, Target Failed to run : Remote exception encountered : 'Failed to get task for pid'

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments

I have no control over the builds. I dont have an apple dev account either. I can use a debug/checked/release build. When running test automation I continue to run into this error: Target failed to run : Remote exception encountered : 'Failed to get task for pid 506'

The automation starts, the application opens and then promptly closes. here is some console output

Oct 25 09:46:48 iphone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.something.dogfood[0xd456][504]) : (UIKitApplication:com.something.dogfood[0xd456]) Exited: Killed: 9

Oct 25 09:46:48 iphone SpringBoard[29] : Application 'MyApplicaton' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661399/instruments-target-failed-to-run

Comment: Here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5457816/1180406

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instruments basically does its work by becoming the debugger for the app.  Sometimes after using XCode to debug apps, I find I can't use Instruments until I reboot the device.

Unlike XCode, Instruments can be confused between two apps with the same name, but different bundle IDs. (Or perhaps same name and similar bundle IDs.)  When I have multiple versions of an app on a device, I often have to delete the extra to get Instruments to connect to the correct app.

So, delete any duplicates of your app and restart the device.

Comment: The entitlements also need to be set to allow debugging.

Comment: I tried all the above and still failed. What finally worked was running the app from XCode with the Profiler up (failed). Then with the app running, click Record on Profiler. App is sigkill'ed in XCode. Click debug Continue in XCode to exit any breakpoints. Click Record in Profiler. Finally, it ran.