# Memory profiling doesn't work with Xcode, just displays "No Selection"

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode9

I am using the latest version of Xcode 9 and macOS 10.13.

When I try to make a memory graph from the current state of my application, it shows an empty screen that says **No Selection**.

[image: "No selection" title after trying to create a memory graph]

I also tried to profile and work with Instruments, but it did not allow me to run due to a permission error.

> Target failed to run.
>
> Permission to debug [app name] was denied.

I am **aware of these threads** and tried the suggestions available in them, but they **didn't seem to work**:

- [Reddit - Has instruments stopped working for you in Xcode 9 due to a permission denied error? Is there a workaround for this?](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/71au2i/has_instruments_stopped_working_for_you_in_xcode/)
- [Apple Developer Forums - Xcode 9 - Instruments permission denied](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87813)
- [Stack Overflow - Why do I get instruments - “Target failed to run”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661399/why-do-i-get-instruments-target-failed-to-run)
- [Stack Overflow - Can't launch my app in Instruments: At least one target failed to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905450/cant-launch-my-app-in-instruments-at-least-one-target-failed-to-launch)

**Things that I tried:**

- Restarting Xcode
- Emptying the Derived Data folder
- Cleaning the project
- Cleaning the Build folder
- Modifying the scheme's application environment to Debug instead of Release
- Manually managing provisioning profiles and selecting Development profiles for Debug and Release
- Trying simulators with different OS versions (iOS 11, iOS 10)

Looks like it's a specific issue with Xcode 9.

Are there any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: I also have this issue. I'm convinced it's caused by provisioning profile issues. I had it working once, but then it stopped working again the next time I tried.

Comment: Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46667604/4439188) it worked for me.

Comment: This is a known bug. Update your Xcode to the latest beta.

Answer (score 5):

I tried building the application on a **physical device** and it worked, hovever, the memory graph did not show my Swift classes (for e.g., my controllers were simply not there). Allocation observing worked fine with Instruments, nonetheless.

It seems like this is an issue caused by the simulator.

Comment: This also worked for me. Still can't do it on the sim, but device works.

Answer (score 1):

In My Case I was Using Xcode 9. When I have checked to Xcode-> Preferences->Locations->Command Line Tools = Xcode 8.3.3 so I just Changed from Xcode 8.3.3 to Xcode 9.0 and It starts working.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the Build Configuration for Profiling was set to Release instead of Debug in the Scheme. After changing it, I could just profile in the Simulator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Guess not, An error occured trying to capture leaks data, unable to acquire required task port (4382:0)

Comment: I'm also getting the error about acquiring a required task port. Seeing it on Xcode 9.3 on my iMac and Xcode 10 on my Mojave MacBook.

Comment: Turned out that my Debug profile was set up to do signing, and that was interfering somehow.