# Visual memory debugging button not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, xcode9

I'm using Xcode 9 and Objectice-C mostly. The visual memory debugging button button in the debug bar doesn't show up in any possible configuration of the scheme. I've also tried to upgrade the deployment target to iOS10 without any luck.

[image]

Am I missing some build settings as this project was created long time ago (I've always update to the Xcode recommended settings in each new release tho)?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not an Xcode release for the fans of memory debugging. [I had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46423639/memory-profiling-doesnt-work-with-xcode-9), although, at least, the option showed up for me.

Comment: I don't have a memory debugger either (Version 9.0 (9A235)). There still no memory debugger in Xcode Version 9.1 beta 2 (9B46)