# Xcode debug memory graph is only showing UIKit

Tags: swift, xcode8

When pressing "Debug Memory Graph" Xcode is only showing me objects from UIKit (and libswiftcore). I'm expecting to see my projects module as well. Any idea how to fix this?

What I've tried so far:
*Restarting my mac*

[image: Debug Memory Graph]

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46423639/3151675) for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it had something to do with filtering, pressing the filter button resolved this issue for me.

[image: Filter button]